# What does this mean “In love’s service only wounded soldiers can serve.”?

Tags: quotes

I just read this quote from [nytimes's opinion section](http://www.nytimes.com/2014/06/24/opinion/david-brooks-rhapsody-in-realism.html?_r=0).

"In love’s service only wounded soldiers can serve."

What does this quote mean? I can faintly feel what it means, but I want to understand it more clearly. Can somebody help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> The mature people one meets often have this crooked timber view,
>   having learned from experience the intransigence of imperfection and
>   how to make a friend of every stupid stumble. As Thornton Wilder once
>   put it, “In love’s service only wounded soldiers can serve.”

It means that you can only know something through loss, and I think bittersweet describes this maturation theme:  Life and love have no perfection, and the illusion of the ideal mars what is the truth.  The recognition that *we are crooked timber. We are, to varying degrees, foolish, weak, and often just plain inexplicable — and always will be* is in itself a prerequisite tool to experiencing life or love.

Comment: Hi, Third News. I really appreciate your help. So, if I paraphrase this quote, would it be something like "Only those who have suffered tragedy or pain can do "real" love?

Comment: Replace 'do' with 'feel' or 'share' love fully

Answer (score 1):

As Pat Benatar taught us, [Love is a Battlefield](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D0EysM1iNMk&feature=kp).

This is a bit of an opinion, but the only way to truly appreciate love is to understand what it isn't and that is a processes that involves a lot of pain and hurt. So, by the time you get into love's service, you've already been wounded in the battle.

I don't personally care for the construction of the sentence, however. Having "service" and then "serve" feels clunky. I would probably change the last "serve" to "enlist" or something, but who am I to challenge Thornton Wilder (no one, that's who).

Comment: Hi, MrsLannister. I really appreciate your help. So, if I paraphrase this quote, would it be something like "Only those who have suffered tragedy or pain can do "real" love"?

Comment: That's not quite right. I'd say more along the lines of "Only the wounded really understand love" or something like that.

Comment: I think "do" is closer than "understand"... although I would rather say "offer".  *Only the wounded (those with experiences of pain) can truly offer love.*